# QEMU: passing usb devices running fullspeed to vm with ehci usb controller running lowspeed

Tags: windows-xp, usb, virtual-machine, qemu

I have Windows XP VM with GPU passthrough and would like also to pass usb keyboard and mouse to it.
I am doing the usb passthrough with:

```
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x1e7d,productid=0xafca \
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x046d,productid=0xc53d \
```

and get errors like:

```
Warning: speed mismatch trying to attach usb device "ROCCAT Kone Air" (full speed) to bus "usb-bus.0", port "1" (high speed)
```

I think the problem might be the usb-ehci controller the vm is running. When I change usb controller to qemu-xhci, the usb devices get passed correctly according to console, but windows xp have no drivers for xhci.

My full VM:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-nodefaults \
-machine pc-i440fx-5.2,accel=kvm,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off \
-name "Windows XP",debug-threads=on \
-cpu Skylake-Client-IBRS,ss=on,vmx=on,pdcm=on,hypervisor=on,tsc-adjust=on,clflushopt=on,umip=on,stibp=on,arch-capabilities=on,xsaves=on,pdpe1gb=on,ibpb=on,amd-stibp=on,skip-l1dfl-vmentry=on,pschange-mc-no=on,hv-time,hv-relaxed,hv-vapic,hv-spinlocks=0x1fff \
-smp sockets=1,cores=4,threads=2 \
-m 4G \
-vga none \
-drive file=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-C300-MTFDBAK128MAG_0000000011250313A6FD,format=raw,cache=none \
-device vfio-pci,host=05:00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=05:00.1,multifunction=on \
-device usb-ehci \
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x1e7d,productid=0xafca \
-device usb-host,vendorid=0x046d,productid=0xc53d \
-net nic,model=rtl8139 \
-net user \
```

What are my options of passing fullspeed usb devices to that vm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do the above with a regular VM App and XP works fine. QEMU passthrough may not handle XP well (I think QEMU came well after XP).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got the speeds wrong.
FullSpeed is 12Mbps, HiSpeed is 480Mbps, so that means I need USB controller compatible with USB version 1.1, and for WinXP and i440fx machine that is `piix3-usb-uhci`. After replacing `usb-ehci` with `piix3-usb-uhci` everything works as intended.